# How do I capture table td elements using mousedown.dragselect event?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which renders a HTML table where each `td` element has an id

What I want to accomplish is to use the `mousedown.dragselect/mouseup.dragselect` to determine which elements have been selected, and then highlight those selected elements. What I have so far is something like this:

```
var $ele = $(this);
scope.bindMultipleSelection = function() {
  element.bind('mousedown.dragselect', function() {
    $document.bind('mousemove.dragselect', scope.mousemove);
    $document.bind('mouseup.dragselect', scope.mouseup);
  });
};

scope.bindMultipleSelection();

scope.mousemove = function(e) {
  scope.selectElement($(this));
};

scope.mouseup = function(e) {
};

scope.selectElement = function($ele) {
  if (!$ele.hasClass('eng-selected-item'))
    $ele.addClass('eng-selected-item'); //apply selection or de-selection to current element
};
```

How can I get every `td` element selected by `mousedown.dragselect`, and be able to get their ids and then highlight them?

Answer (score 12):

I suspect using anything relating to dragging won't give you what you want. Dragging is actually used when moving elements about (e.g. dragging files in My Computer / Finder), when what you're after is multiple selection.

So there a number of things the directive needs:

- Listen to `mousedown`, `mouseenter` and `mouseup`,  events.

  - `mousedown` should listen on the cells of the table, and set a "dragging" mode.
  - `mouseenter` should listen on the cells as well, and if the directive is in dragging mode, select the "appropriate cells"
  - `mouseup` should disable dragging mode, and actually be on the whole body, in case the mouse is lifted up while the cursor is not over the table.
- [jQuery delegation](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is useful here, as it can nicely delegate the above events to the table, so the code is much more friendly to cells that are added after this directive is initialised. (I wouldn't include or use jQuery in an Angular project unless you have a clear reason like this).
- Although you've not mentioned it, the "appropriate cells" I suspect all the cells "between" where the mouse was clicked, and the current cell, chosen in a rectangle, and *not* just the cells that have been entered while the mouse was held down. To find these, [`cellIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement) and [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex) can be used, together with [filtering](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) all the cells from the table.
- All the listeners should be wrapped `$scope.$apply` to make sure Angular runs a digest cycle after they fire.
- For the directive to communicate the ids of the selected elements to the surrounding scope, the directive can use bi-directional binding using the `scope` property, and the `=` symbol, as explained in the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Putting all this together gives:

```
app.directive('dragSelect', function($window, $document) {
  return {
    scope: {
      dragSelectIds: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      var cls = 'eng-selected-item';
      var startCell = null;
      var dragging = false;

      function mouseUp(el) {
        dragging = false;
      }

      function mouseDown(el) {
        dragging = true;
        setStartCell(el);
        setEndCell(el);
      }

      function mouseEnter(el) {
        if (!dragging) return;
        setEndCell(el);
      }

      function setStartCell(el) {
        startCell = el;
      }

      function setEndCell(el) {
        $scope.dragSelectIds = [];
        $element.find('td').removeClass(cls);
        cellsBetween(startCell, el).each(function() {
          var el = angular.element(this);
          el.addClass(cls);
          $scope.dragSelectIds.push(el.attr('id'));
        });
      }

      function cellsBetween(start, end) {
        var coordsStart = getCoords(start);
        var coordsEnd = getCoords(end);
        var topLeft = {
          column: $window.Math.min(coordsStart.column, coordsEnd.column),
          row: $window.Math.min(coordsStart.row, coordsEnd.row),
        };
        var bottomRight = {
          column: $window.Math.max(coordsStart.column, coordsEnd.column),
          row: $window.Math.max(coordsStart.row, coordsEnd.row),
        };
        return $element.find('td').filter(function() {
          var el = angular.element(this);
          var coords = getCoords(el);
          return coords.column >= topLeft.column
              && coords.column <= bottomRight.column
              && coords.row >= topLeft.row
              && coords.row <= bottomRight.row;
        });
      }

      function getCoords(cell) {
        var row = cell.parents('row');
        return {
          column: cell[0].cellIndex, 
          row: cell.parent()[0].rowIndex
        };
      }

      function wrap(fn) {
        return function() {
          var el = angular.element(this);
          $scope.$apply(function() {
            fn(el);
          });
        }
      }

      $element.delegate('td', 'mousedown', wrap(mouseDown));
      $element.delegate('td', 'mouseenter', wrap(mouseEnter));
      $document.delegate('body', 'mouseup', wrap(mouseUp));
    }
  }
});
```

Another thing that will make the experience a bit nicer, is to set the cursor to a pointer, and [disable text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407335/1319998)

```
[drag-select] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

You can also see this in action in this [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cCsLf6g83Xhg72mePoFf?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Michal Charemza,   Thank you for your response, your solution work for me.

Comment: I modified a little bit to be used by other directives. I used  $rootScope.$broadcast('DRAG_SELECTED_UPDATE',$scope.dragSelectIds);

Comment: Using `$rootScope.$broadcast` might end up being limiting in the long run, as it will make it difficult to have more than one of such tables in the same app at the same time.

Comment: What do you suggest to do instead of using $rootScope.$broadcast?

Comment: Ok. I used  http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/12/17/communicating-between-directives-in-angularjs/ instead of using  $rootScope.$broadcast

Comment: I believe `$scope.dragSelectIds = [];` should be changed to `$scope.dragSelectIds.length = 0;`, otherwise the original scope variable will not be updated.

Comment: Is there any way to keep a square/rectangular selection if there are colspans/rowspans (of greater than 1) on some of the cells?